# SSIS errors are coming while loading the dynamic excel into ssms table

Tags: sql-server, excel, etl, ssis

I am trying to load excel into SSMS Tables dynamically. I am facing the below issues. i kept REASON field length as max for the data type of nvarchar(max).
I tried with nvarchar(4000), still receiving the same errors.

> [Excel Source [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
>   [Excel Source [12]] Error: Failed to retrieve long data for column "REASON".
>   [Excel Source [12]] Error: There was an error with Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[REASON] on Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output]. The column status returned was: "DBSTATUS_UNAVAILABLE".
>   [Excel Source [12]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[REASON]" failed because error code 0xC0209071 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Excel Source.Outputs[Excel Source Output].Columns[REASON]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
>   [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Excel Source returned error code 0xC0209029.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I can't share the data here since it's client data. Please let me know on this will be appreciated.

Comment: An old very well known problem with SSIS and Excel, where you cannot easily import columns longer than 255 characters. After more than 10 years MS still could not be bothered fixing it. There is no proper solution for it either, just various workarounds and hacks. Google for "sql server SSIS change varchar size excel"

Comment: As @Alex mentioned you can try a method like this: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/860660/Excel-source-having-more-than-255-characters

Comment: Excel always causes problems for importing mostly because you are not allowed to determine data types. You need this to come in as a ntext data type. you can convert ntext to nvarchar(4000) and further to varchar(4000) if wanted

Comment: with that being said, if the first 8 rows do not contain a string over 255 you might find failure. you have to amend the connection string in order for ssis to look past 8 rows to determine data type.

Comment: is there any other alternative for the below one ? SSIS bases its datatypes on a sampling of the records (8 rows by default) from the Excel file. If none of the records in the sample are longer than 255 characters, you cannot set the field to memo.

You can change the sample size by changing the value of TypeGuessRows in the registry key for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel.